Prevent sharing Internet via hotspot by my wifi router
I have a wifi router that allowes only devices to access internet thorugh their MAC but in mobile device I want to know how to prevent users to access internet throught hotspot of my allowed device and similary to block chain of network allowed.
I will be happy for any solution either through any other router that has such capability as my current router only block direct connection not indirect.

You can’t; What you want won’t be possible with the hardware you have. Are you aware that MAC address whitelists are trivial to bypass?

not aware about this, but what could be the solution that won't allow to access internet indirectly

There isn’t one; You would have to take control over the mobile phone through a corporate policy and prevent the hotspot functionality from being enabled. I am guessing you don’t have that ability to do so.

Use Ethernet. Any consumer version of WiFi has limited security, though WPA3 is curently best. See https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/feature/Wireless-encryption-basics-Understanding-WEP-WPA-and-WPA2
